# requirejs shim amd library dependencies

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I understand how to use requirejs config to set up dependencies between non-AMD libraries like backbone and underscore. It's my understanding that shim is only for non-AMD libraries. How do I use requirejs to set up a dependency between AMD libraries? Will something like this work?

```
require.config( {
      paths: {
            backbone             : "lib/backbone-min",
            jquery        : "lib/jquery-1.10.1.min",
            liba : 'lib/AMD-compliant-lib-a',
            libb : 'lib/AMD-compliant-lib-b-that-depends-on-a'
      },
      shim: {
            backbone: {
                  "deps": [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
                  "exports": "Backbone"  
            }, 
            underscore: {
                "exports": '_' 
            }, 
            libb: {
                "deps" : liba
            }
      },

} );
```

Answer (score 2):

shim can also be used to `define the dependencies of AMD modules`. So that will works except `deps` expects an array.

So try this

```
   shim: {
        backbone: {
              deps: [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
              exports: "Backbone"  
        }, 
        underscore: {
            exports: '_' 
        }, 
        libb: {
            deps : ["liba"]
        }
  }
```